# Handling an exception on items in a for-each loop

Tags: c#

I couldn't think of a good way to test it myself so asking this question:
Lets say I have a list of transactions that I have sending them one by one to a web service and the result of webservice call may be Success, Failed or something weird may have happened and it just crashes.
So the overall code I have is like this:

```
for each (transaction)
{
   try
   {
      string result = webservice.Call(transaction);
      if result == "Faild"
      {
          // log some errors.
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Log some errors, stack trace, etc...
    }
}
```

So my question is: if it falls into an exception for one of the transaction calls, then does the whole thing stop? OR it will get out of the exception block and will move on to next item in the for-each?

Comment: That's entirely up to you.  Either response to the error can be logically correct, if that's how the error should be meaningfully handled in that situation.  Based on the business logic you're conducting, *should* you continue with other records or *should* you stop processing and notify the user?

Comment: `it will get out of the exception block and will move on to next item in the for-each`. This is general code execution flow, until force to come out of loop from `catch` block (like using `return` or `break`).

Comment: +1, because from a naive Question, produced a general helpful answer (jgauffin's)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `catch` is a catch and will do what a catch is supposed to do.

The loop will not break unless you rethrow the exception.

If you want to complete the entire loop before telling the user that something went wrong you can do 
something like this:

```
List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();
foreach (var transaction in transactions)
{
   try
   {
      string result = webservice.Call(transaction);
      if result == "Faild"
      {
          // log some errors.
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       exceptions.Add(ex);
    }
}

if (exceptions.Any())
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
```

Comment: "If you want to complete the entire loop before telling the user that something went wrong "  Yes that's what I wanted to do. So I can write to an EventLog table the exceptions that have occurred and call stack of each of them.

Comment: @DevWannaBe: Just replace the `throw new AggregateException` with your logging logic.

Comment: @DevWannaBe If this answered your question please make sure to mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

It **WILL** continue looping until you have no more transactions to loop through.  That's what is so useful about try catch.

Answer (score 1):

Since the try/catch is inside the loop, it will run for each transaction call.
If you had put the loop inside the try, then it would blow up at the first exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx) on using `try { ... } catch() { ... } finally { ... }`, where you can have code that executes after the exception is handled.